# How can I asynchronously add controls to a asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I'm looking to optimize pages within our application so they perform better. I want to dynamically add controls (Textbox, Button, Custom Control, etc) to a page using AJAX to minimize postbacks done. I'm looking for an alternative to using an UpdatePanel (nothing wrong with them, they're just not built for performance).

The trick though is that the ViewState will need to be updated with the new controls added, so I can't see WebServices or static Page Method calls fitting in well here.

Comment: If you're considering these kinds of optimizations, you should consider not using ASP.NET AJAX at all, and instead use a framework like jQuery for all your Ajax. I don't know any professional .NET web developers working on performant enterprise solutions that use ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls cannot update viewstate as that is created in code behind.

Maybe if you manage to access the viewstate server side you could send it back in the ajax call and store it in the viewstate field but you risk loosing anything that was not touched in the callback, I have never delved that deep into viewstate.

Comment: Yes, this is why I've thought of using a handler, since then I can still process a page request. Ajax calls to a page do not instantiate a full page process. I'd love to know of anyones experience in this.

Comment: You can activate session state in web methods, but I do not know about view state as that is serialized from the page and unless all controls initialize it can be difficult to deserialize it.